# Find an element in a binary tree

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree

How can I search for an element in a binary tree that is not a bst?

This is an example of how my tree looks

```
      1
     / \
    2   3
   / \ / \
  4  5 6  7
```

This is what I'm doing:

```
treeNode * find(treeNode *T, int x) {
    if(T == NULL) return NULL;
    if(x == T -> element) {
        return T;
    }
    find(T -> left, x);
    find(T -> right, x);
    return NULL;
}
```

The problem is that the recursion does not stop when the if is satisfied

Comment: Have you tried checking every node to see if it's the element you're looking for? If so, what issues are you having with that solution? If not, give that a try.

Comment: Depth-First Search should be covered in any decent algorithm text-book.  Seems like you setup your example for a breath-first search which is slightly more difficult to implement than DFS.

Comment: You can simply check if one of the nodes is equal to your key you are looking for? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: When you recursively call `find`, you should do something with the return values. That's how you detect a successful search, no?

Comment: @TimRandall Yes thats right but I can't find a way to do that

Comment: Your mistake is that you never check what the recursed function is returning.

Comment: afaik this is the topmost confusion with recursion. I find it interesting, because its only with recursion that beginners expect return values to magically travel up the call stack. Try to forget about the recursion for a moment and consider that the very first call can only return `NULL` unless it is already the searched for element.

Comment: But your tree doesn't contain sorted data! Usually left child contain values less then value in current node and rigth child has values grater then current node value! If you do not have sorted data, then you can't do binary search on that tree! So what is the point of having a binary tree here?

Comment: @MarekR -- In context to " *So what is the point of having a binary tree here?* " - what if the choice of the data-structure was not up to you (or the OP)?  Also, the OP did not say they want to do a *binary search on the tree* -- just search the binary tree.

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps my point was that OP most probably missed important part of his task. It would be better if he finds item in `O(log n)` time then in `O(n)` time and sees that difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're ignoring the return values from your recursive calls:

```
treeNode * find(treeNode *T, int x) {
    if(T == NULL) return NULL;
    if(x == T -> element) {
        return T;
    }
    treeNode *result = find(T -> left, x);
    if ( result ) // if the return value was found, this will not be NULL, so return the node
        return result;
    return find(T -> right, x); // will return NULL if its not found
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing return statements for your recursive calls. So not only does the recursion continue, but the value is never returned to the original caller.

```
treeNode * find(treeNode *T, int x) {
    if(T == NULL) return NULL;
    if(x == T -> element) {
        return T;
    }
   auto findLeft = find(T -> left, x)
   if (findLeft) return findLeft;
   return find(T -> right, x);
}
```

Comment: Ah, I'm not familiar with cpp and assumed it would return whichever ptr is truthy. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

In context to -

> The problem is that the recursion does not stop when the if is satisfied

-the reason is because you must check if your recursive calls return a valid result and stop searching further.

Change -

```
find(T -> left, x);
find(T -> right, x);
```

-to something like -

```
    treeNode* result = find(T -> left, x);
    if (result != NULL)
        return result;
    return find(T -> right, x);
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the results of each attempt to find `x`

```
treeNode * find(treeNode *T, int x) {
    if(T == NULL) return NULL;
    if(x == T -> element) {
        return T;
    }
    treeNode* result = find(T -> left, x);
    if (result)
        return result;

    result = find(T -> right, x);
    if (result)
        return result;

    return NULL;
}
```

ETA: the end of this can be simplified. Returning `result` if it's not `NULL` and returning `NULL` otherwise... is the same as returning `result`. All we're doing, really, is returning the value returned from the call to `find`. So...

```
treeNode * find(treeNode *T, int x) {
    if(T == NULL) return NULL;
    if(x == T -> element) {
        return T;
    }
    treeNode* result = find(T -> left, x);
    if (result)
        return result;

    return find(T -> right, x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Binary trees are usually used to keep data sorted and quickly add/find items in that order.

Without order binary tree doesn't have many applications. So when I see your picture of tree I suspect that you have missed most important property of b-trees and probably important part of your task.

If you note that order is important in your task then take a look at that code:

```cpp
class Node;

using NodePtr = std::uniqeu_ptr<Node>;
class Node
{
    int value;
    NodePtr left;
    NodePtr right;
};

void insert(NodePtr &node, int value)
{
    if (node) {
       insert((value < node->value) ? node->left : node->right, value);
    } else {
       node.reset(new Node{value});
    }
}

Node* find(Node* node, int value)
{
    if (!node) {
       return nullptr;
    }
    if (node->value == value) {
       return node.get();
    }
    return find((value < node->value) ? node->left.get() : node->right.get(), value);
}
```